# Analytic solution to two component, first order, linear PDE system

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, hyperbolic-pde

I would like to obtain analytic solutions to the following PDE system:
\begin{equation}
\rho_t + D(\lambda)\,\rho_\lambda = A(\lambda) \rho, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $\rho = (\rho_0,\rho_1)^T$, $D$ is the diagonal matrix
\begin{equation}
 D(\lambda) = \begin{pmatrix} -(1+a)\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & p_b-\lambda\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
and the matrix $A$ depends on $\lambda$ alone, through component functions of the form $ \frac{\lambda^2 + a \lambda + b}{c \lambda + d}$.

I am aware of the fact that questions of this type have been asked before on MathOverflow. However, system $(1)$ has certain features which make it, in my opinion, worthwhile to devote a new question to it.

- System $(1)$ is non-homogeneous (i.e. $A \neq 0$), so it cannot be interpreted as a conservation equation.
- The left hand side of $(1)$ is in diagonal form, while $A$ has no nonzero components. In other words, $D$ and $A$ are not simultaneously diagonalizable.

While I am aware of the fact that 'There is no generally applicable method of characterstics for first order systems' (@Igor Khavkine's comment on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/241917/method-of-characteristic-for-a-system-of-first-order-pdes)), I would hope that the characteristic surface spanned by the two characteristics defined by the left hand side of $(1)$ could be used to solve $(1)$ by a generalisation of the method of characteristics.

Since system $(1)$ does not have constant coefficients, previous questions such as [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186779/reference-request-systems-of-linear-pdes-with-constant-coefficients?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190850/system-of-linear-first-order-pde-with-constant-coefficients), and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231589/solving-a-general-constant-coefficient-first-order-two-indep-variable-system) do not apply, as far as I can see. Moreover, the nonvanishing right hand side of $(1)$ makes the situation qualitatively different from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103916/classification-of-a-certain-system-of-linear-first-order-pdes-whose-characterist) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193330/method-of-characteristics-of-a-system-of-first-order-pdes?rq=1) question. Also, system $(1)$ cannot be reduced in a manner demonstrated in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171969/analytic-solution-of-a-system-of-linear-hyperbolic-first-order-partial-differ?rq=1) question or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193330/method-of-characteristics-of-a-system-of-first-order-pdes?rq=1) question.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What are the entries of A?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the entries of A are rational functions of the type specified, containing parameters not found in D. In other words, the best thing to do is just to treat $A(\lambda)$ as an unspecified $2 \times 2$ matrix, with entries dependent on $\lambda$ in an unspecified way. The explicit form of the actual entries is quite involved, and not very insightful.